# Why does drush rsync require a local site?

Tags: drush

It's clearly documented that [`drush rsync`](http://drush.ws/#core-rsync) requires one of the sites to be local.  I'd like to understand why this restriction is in place.  I have configured site aliases to work with `ssh`, and I'm able to ssh into a system and then launch `drush rsync`.  Why can't [drush](/questions/tagged/drush) do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drush just performs the following in commands/core/rsync.core.inc:

```
$exec = "rsync -e 'ssh $ssh_options' $options $source $destination";
```

This isn't compatible with rsync daemons, as stated in the rsync manual:

> you must not specify the --rsh (-e) option.

Now, if you want to use drush to rsync between two remote environments, you'll need to install Drush on the source, then:

```
drush rsync @remote.source @remote.target
```

Comment: This answer is completely correct.  Some extra info: there was some work to get drush to work with rsync daemons at https://drupal.org/node/1473524.  It seems, though, that if you want to do that, then you are better off calling rsync directly, and use "drush dd" to look up the paths you need.